# Jenkis CLI does not work: WARNING: No header 'X-SSH-Endpoint' returned by Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I have `Jenkins ver. 2.205` in `Windows 10` and I have the following situation

- `Configure Global Security` has `Enable security` checked.
- I created the `id_rsa_jenkins` and `id_rsa_jenkins.pub` keys. The value of the public key was added to Jenkins for my account in `SSH Public Keys`.
- I have the `jenkins-cli.jar` file, downloaded from `http://localhost:9090/cli/`

### CLI

When I execute the following (split in multiple lines for presentation purposes):

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar 
          -s http://localhost:9090/ 
          -i C:\Users\windowsusername/.ssh/id_rsa_jenkins 
          -ssh 
          -user jenkinsusername 
          help
```

Appears:

```
Enter passphrase for C:\Users\windowsusername\.ssh\id_rsa_jenkins:
```

### Problem

I write the valid *passphrase* and then appears the following:

```
Nov 23, 2019 11:28:22 AM org.apache.sshd.common.util.security.AbstractSecurityProviderRegistrar getOrCreateProvider
INFO: getOrCreateProvider(EdDSA) created instance of net.i2p.crypto.eddsa.EdDSASecurityProvider
Nov 23, 2019 11:28:22 AM hudson.cli.SSHCLI sshConnection
WARNING: No header 'X-SSH-Endpoint' returned by Jenkins
```

As shown above, does not appear the expected data

It happens for any `Jenkins CLI` command, such as:

- help
- who-am-i
- list-jobs

etc.

What is missing or wrong?

Comment: Why do you need the same 2 questions on a different SE sites https://superuser.com/questions/1504516/jenkis-cli-does-not-work-warning-no-header-x-ssh-endpoint-returned-by-jenkin

Comment: Because many times in one place gives a reply and the other not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the audience:

The instructions provided in the original post are mandatory. But the following instructions are mandatory too:

- Have installed the `SSH` plugin
- In `Configure Global Security`, in the `SSH Server` section (in the bottom), proceed to enable it, in this case I use the `Fixed` value option.

**Note** seems the `random` option is only useful for the `jenkins-cli.jar` case. It because through the `SSH` connection (i.e: `ssh -l jenkinsusername -p 2020 localhost list-jobs`) is mandatory know the port, in this case `2020`.

Therefore `Fixed` or `Random` is viable for `jenkins-cli.jar` (it does not ask for use a port number) but for `SSH` connection is mandatory know the port number (here `Fixed` is need it)

Furthemore in [Jenkins SSH](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+SSH) indicates:

```
Configuration

By default, Jenkins will listen on a random available port, so as not to break 
existing deployments. But this is most likely not very useful, so the administrator 
is encouraged to change this from the global security configuration page by assigning 
a fixed port. This configuration UI will also allow you to disable this feature.
```

Was very valuable this video:

- [Jenkins in Telugu part 17 | Jenkins CLI (with ssh)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJC4wOwfIUk)